# Print menu and output as selectlist

Tags: theming, navigation

is there possibilty to print menu and output as selectlist ?

```
<?php
  // https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_tree_all_data/7
$tree = menu_tree_all_data('menu-example');
menu_tree_add_active_path($tree);
echo drupal_render(menu_tree_output($tree));
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this within the template tpl like that. You still wind up calling `render` which pipes the array back to a theme function anyway. You will need to override the corresponding theme hook that is rendering the menu and links to do what you want.

It almost sounds like you want a jump menu, to which I would first direct you here to [Jump Menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/jump_menu).

Overriding theme hook(s) for menu and menu links is a fairly daunting task.

Comment: Please don't add code in comments. Jump Menu will output a menu in a select list like you are trying to do.

Comment: Is there possibility to do with jump menu: taxonomy1(parent) > node1(child), node2(child) and taxonomy2(parent) > node3(child), node4(child) and taxonomy3(parent) > node5(child)

Comment: I don't know what that means. Jump Menus purpose is to output a menu as a select list.

Comment: Well taxonomy will show nodes etc parent--> nodes. I got city-term and I need to show all nodes what based in this city.

Comment: What does that have to do with showing a menu? Does this menu even exist? The code in your question makes it seem so.

Comment: well I got already taxonomy menu. Is there any good idea put to jump menu?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57049/discussion-between-joona-and-kevin).